# I have a program that should write some data to a file, it does not and I have no idea why

Tags: java, file-io

I have a simple program that needs to write a few lines of string to a file using `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter`. It already reads the (in this case) exact same data from the file, it stores it in runtime memory, but it outright refuses to write it and I have no idea why. Usually I'd try to debug it and see what's happening but I have no idea what I'm looking for.

**Here is my code:**

```
public void close () {
    FileWriter output = null;
    BufferedWriter fileOut = null;

    // I use the exact same method to read from file so this should work
    // this.prajituri :: ArrayList
    // toString is @Override

    try {
        output = new FileWriter(this.fileName);
        fileOut = new BufferedWriter(output);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.prajituri.size(); i++) {
            fileOut.write(prajituri.get(i).toString());
            System.out.println(prajituri.get(i).toString());
            fileOut.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Output error: " + ioe);
    } finally {
        if (fileOut != null)
            fileOut = null;
        if (output != null)
            output = null;
    }
}
```

Just in case, here is my toString:

```
@Override
public String toString () {
    return this.name + ";" + this.weight + ";" + this.price;
}
```

Every time I try to write to file, it gives me an empty file. Am I doing something wrong ?

I checked and `this.prajituri` is actually good (has all the data it should have)
And I use the `System.out.println(prajituri.get(i).toString())` to check what it **Should** write and that is OK also. Yet it writes nothing.

Comment: `if (fileOut != null) fileOut.close;` rather than `fileOut = null;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write to disk immediately:

```
output.flush();
```

When done:

```
output.close();
```

`close( )` includes `flush( )`

Comment: So then I don't need to flush **BEFORE** I write, do I ?

Comment: No.  writes are saved in a buffer.  flush forces the buffer to disk.

Answer (score 4):

you have to close your **BufferedWriter** [`fileOut.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29)

Comment: +1, although alternatively you could flush it and let the system close it for you, but this should solve the problem.

Comment: @corsiKa - the system won't close it for you, you will end up with a file handle leak if you don't call close explicitly.

Comment: @Paolo I shouldn't make comments before my morning coffee. You're absolutely right. The only time it would close it for you is when the process ends, and that's not exactly a good practice to be in...

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the stream to write it to disk.

[flush in java.io.FileWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742361/flush-in-java-io-filewriter)

You should close the stream properly by calling `fileout.close()` (which will internally call the flush anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You have to flush/ close your stream. If you're using Java SE 7, the easiest way is to use the new Automatic Resource Management feature:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html